# how to calculate average for multiple tables of filtered data dynamically - VBA

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, dynamic-arrays, vba

I have a table where I need to find the elements present in different samples. 
For every sample, the no of iterations is a variable - I can have two rows of sample 1 and 3 rows of sample2 or 5 rows of sample4. the number of columns which are the elements can also be different. I have considered 3 samples and 17 elements in this case. 
I need to filter based on the sample. say sample 1. Then the average needs to be calculated for all the entries of sample 1. Then below that sample 2 values need to be displayed and the average for all the entries of sample 2 should be calculated.

I am a beginner in vba and hence the code I used is not able to do it for dynamic range of values. Also, I can only calculate the average using macro recorder. I am not aware how to combine these two codes into one. I tried to search a lot on this topic

I have included my codes as well. 
Any help would be much appreciated!!! Thank you

```
Sub sorttable()
Dim j As Long 'row variable
On Error GoTo Err_Execute
Dim i As Long
'Start search in row 1 in sheet1
j = 1
'Column counter for sheet2
i = 1
While Len(Range("A" & CStr(j)).Value) > 0


If Range("A" & CStr(j)).Value = "Sample1" Then
Range(Range("A" & CStr(j)), Range("A" & CStr(j)).End(xlToRight)).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Sheet2.Cells(i, 1).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False
'Cells(j + 1, 1) = "=AVERAGE(A1:C" & j - 1 & ")" 'used to calculate avg
i = i + 1
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
ElseIf Range("A" & CStr(j)).Value = "Sample2" Then
Range(Range("A" & CStr(j)), Range("A" & CStr(j)).End(xlToRight)).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Sheet2.Cells(i, 1).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False
i = i + 1
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
ElseIf Range("A" & CStr(j)).Value = "Sample3" Then
Range(Range("A" & CStr(j)), Range("A" & CStr(j)).End(xlToRight)).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Sheet2.Cells(i, 1).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False
i = i + 1
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
End If
j = j + 1
Wend
Application.CutCopyMode = False
MsgBox "the values have been extracted"
Exit Sub
Err_Execute:
MsgBox "Error Occured"
End Sub
'code- part of it for calculating the average
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A9:B9"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("A9:B9").Select
Range("B9").Select
Selection.ClearContents
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "= AVERAGE(R[-2]C,R[-1]C)"
Range("B9").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B9:R9"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("B9:R9").Select
Range("A11").Select
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Range("A27").Select
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("A8:R10").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Range("A11").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A14").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Style = "Normal 2"
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Average"
Range("B14").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "= AVERAGE(R[-3]C:R[-1]C)"
Range("B14").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B14:R14"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("B14:R14").Select
Range("A16").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Collecting Average from multiple sheets in Vba](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13001856/collecting-average-from-multiple-sheets-in-vba)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've recorded your macro as a start, then tried to modify it from there. This is an excellent first step, so now there are things to be aware of:

1. The macro recorder captures many, many things that are unnecessary, so don't use `Select` or `Activate`.
2. Since your data may not be the same for each sample group, your code has to take that into account. Review the sample code below and notice that it loops to figure out how many rows are in a sample group, then dynamically fills in the formula for the columns of that group.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SortTable()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Dim numSampleRows As Long
    numSampleRows = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - 1

    Dim sampleRow As Range
    Set sampleRow = ws.Range("A2")

    Dim i As Long
    Dim numSamplesInGroup As Long
    Dim currentSampleLabel As String
    Dim numSampleColumns As Long
    Dim avgRow As Long
    Dim avgCol As Long
    For i = 1 To (numSampleRows + 1)
        '--- look at the sample labels to determine how
        '    many are in this group
        If numSamplesInGroup = 0 Then
            '--- this is the start of a sample group
            currentSampleLabel = sampleRow.Offset(0, 0)
            numSamplesInGroup = 1
        ElseIf currentSampleLabel = sampleRow.Offset(0, 0) Then
            '--- continue to count the samples in the group
            numSamplesInGroup = numSamplesInGroup + 1
        Else
            '--- we've reached the end of the sample group
            '    so insert two empty rows here
            sampleRow.EntireRow.Insert
            sampleRow.EntireRow.Insert
            Debug.Print sampleRow.Address

            '--- create the AVERAGE formula for each populated column
            '    ASSUMES all the columns are consistent for each sample group
            avgRow = sampleRow.Offset(-2, 0).Row
            ws.Cells(avgRow, 1) = "Average"
            numSampleColumns = ws.Cells(avgRow - 1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            For avgCol = 1 To (numSampleColumns - 1)
                sampleRow.Offset(-2, avgCol).FormulaR1C1 = _
                        "=AVERAGE(R" & _
                           avgRow - numSamplesInGroup & _
                        "C" & avgCol + 1 & _
                        ":R" & avgRow - 1 & "C" & avgCol + 1 & ")"
            Next avgCol

            '--- reset for the next loop
            currentSampleLabel = sampleRow.Offset(0, 0)
            numSamplesInGroup = 0
        End If
        '--- move down one row
        Set sampleRow = sampleRow.Offset(1, 0)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is great help . I appreciate it. I have a question .. Is there a way to mention the offset to be the numofsamplesingroup rather than giving a fixed number. Kindly advice

Comment: Sure. Instead of subtracting the offset to populate your AVERAGE row, you'd need to capture the row number of the start of the sample group, then use `numSamplesInGroup` in the offset to correctly populate the AVERAGE row.